# Date minus Date "Work Days"

Tags: jquery

I would like to get work days from my windows calendar.
For example

```
17.06.2016 - 09.05.2016 = 5
```

Do you know how to do it? It`s there any function?

```
09.05.2016 - work

10.05.2016 - work

11.05.2016 - work

12.05.2016 - work

13.05.2016 - National Day "calendar" - home

14.05.2016 - Weekend - home

15.05.2016 - Weekend - home

16.05.2016 - National Day "calendar" - home

17.05.2016 - work
```

Comment: Do you have two dates as input and need to count the work days in the interval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to do something like this:

```
 function getWorkingDays(startDate, endDate){
    var numberOfDays = 0;
    var currentDate = startDate;
    while (currentDate <= endDate)  {  
        var weekDay = currentDate.getDay();
        if(weekDay != 0 && weekDay != 6)
            result++;

         currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+1); 
    }
    return result;
 }

 var begin = new Date(2016, 05, 9);
 var end = new Date(2016, 06, 17);
 alert(getWorkingDays(begin, end)); // this will output 5
```

Comment: How you add  National Day "calendar"?

Comment: I don't know understand what you mean by that sorry

Comment: for example if you have christmas it`s national day and people don't go to work.

Comment: It`s not this what I need but I will accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorrry I couldn't fully help you but this example should give you a starting point to achieve what you want atleast :)